# How to fix "This site can't be reached" error on localhost?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, antd

Installed the AntDesign into VS code by using `npm install --save antd` and this [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zf5E.jpg) prompt.

- Environment- Node.js & Library - React

Then, I uninstalled the Ant design, deleted the `node_modules` ran the `npm install` and Restart the VS code but still the same error prompts.

Comment: have you tried to run `npm run start` after running `npm install`?

Comment: @RishabhRaghwendra  Already ran this code after `npm install` but the same error occurred.

Comment: please attach package.json file also in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I went through all the steps above mentioned. But none of them fix the error.

The solution for this error is, When the error occurs I utilized Node.js Version 20. Then I downgraded the Node.js to Version 16, ran the `npm install`.